# How to add one extension to standard stack after Pinky?

Tags: dotcloud, cloudcontrol

From this [article](http://www.paasfinder.com/custom-php-version/) I understand that after September 14th CloudControl will have PHP 5.6 as new standard PHP version and a list of extensions enabled by default.

I understood that these extensions are only loaded once no extensions are specified in composer.json.

Does this mean that if one e.g. wants to activate apcu for the standard behaviour he has to mention not only apcu but any other extension which is required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is required to list all extensions in this case.

Comment: Hm, ok, but this can really cause some pain, but I will give it a try.

Comment: For an easy start the default extensions are added. As soon as you are working with additional extension you are aware of the concept of extensions, so there shoud be no big hurdle to define the necessary extensions in your composer.json. The default extensions are also listed in the build process.

Answer (score 1):

Just in the case the linked article disappears and anyone needs it ... here is the list with all the extensions that are enabled by default (copied from the mentioned article):

`composer.json`

```
{
  "require": {
    "php-64bit": "~5.6",
    "ext-amqp": "*",
    "ext-bcmath": "*",
    "ext-bz2": "*",
    "ext-calendar": "*",
    "ext-dba": "*",
    "ext-exif": "*",
    "ext-ftp": "*",
    "ext-curl": "*",
    "ext-gd": "*",
    "ext-gettext": "*",
    "ext-imagick": "*",
    "ext-intl": "*",
    "ext-mbstring": "*",
    "ext-mcrypt": "*",
    "ext-memcached": "*",
    "ext-mongo": "*",
    "ext-mssql": "*",
    "ext-mysql": "*",
    "ext-mysqli": "*",
    "ext-mysqlnd": "*",
    "ext-newrelic": "*",
    "ext-oauth": "*",
    "ext-pdo": "*",
    "ext-pdo_dblib": "*",
    "ext-pdo_mysql": "*",
    "ext-pdo_pgsql": "*",
    "ext-pdo_sqlite": "*",
    "ext-pgsql": "*",
    "ext-shmop": "*",
    "ext-soap": "*",
    "ext-sockets": "*",
    "ext-sqlite3": "*",
    "ext-sysvmsg": "*",
    "ext-sysvsem": "*",
    "ext-sysvshm": "*",
    "ext-wddx": "*",
    "ext-xmlrpc": "*",
    "ext-xsl": "*",
    "ext-zip": "*",
    "ext-zlib": "*"
  }
}
```

---

**Note:** There is also a PHP info available which contains the corresponding extension configuration for the default Pinky stack: http://phpinfo.cloudcontrolled.com/